# What is the difference between the SculptDraw brush and the Brush tool?

Tags: sculpting

What is the difference between the *F SculptDraw* and the *F Brush* tools in sculpt mode?

From what I can see they appear the same:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no practical difference so far as I know. Other brush types also have this apparent duplication, for example texture paint and vertex paint have both a *Draw* and a *Mix* brush that do the same thing.

Comment: In texture painting there are three similar brushes (they are different, but I don't know what the exact differences are) here is an [example](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/61950).

In vertex painting there are three other brushes that also seem the same. ([example](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/61949))

Answer (score 6):

Other than a couple of adjustable default settings, this looks like the only difference.

[image]

Comment: Draw should say Brush, but they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I went through every setting and the only difference that I can see is the one of them has the *Texture Brush Mapping* set to *View Plane* and one has this value set to be *Tiled*. This is not significant enough to justify an extra brush.

I'm guessing that this is just an oversight from some testing a developer was working on but you'd likely have to ask one of them.  I think Psy-Fi is doing most of the *Brush Tools* work right now. He is usually on IRC in #blendercoders on freenode. You could drop by and ask. I suspect that he is top of the food chain so far as this question goes.

Comment: They are in blender all the way back to at least 2.63 (the oldest version I have on my hard drive atm)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the answers give you will see something important. These brushes have input from a Wacom pad such as the brush angle, pressure and location. I think it might change more if you have these inputs.

You can also set the rotation of the texture manually if you look at the nettings in the N settings area.

More importantly, try these two brushes with a texture using a picture of a white lines on a black background. Make sure that your dynamic texture is on and set to 1 pixel (yes it might overload older computers so go with 5 or so). With brush you will not see much happening but with sculpt draw you will see your texture on your mesh. A huge difference!

Douglas E Knapp. Hope this helps! Email me if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

To see the differences, go to Outliner Editor>Datablocks Information Display>Brushes and then open the Brush that you desire and expand RNA to see the setup.

The "Brush" Brush has a 1 pixel radius whereas the Draw and SculptDraw brushes are set to 35 pixels.
The Unprojected Radius varies among all three brushes.
The Sculpt Draw Brush has a 10% spacing whereas the Brush and Draw brushes are set to 5%.
Everything else appears to be identical.

X = Cycles between Brush, Draw and SculptDraw Brushes.
- Blender 2.72b

[image]