# Where to find F Brush tool?

Tags: interface, sculpting

I just downloaded blender 2.75a. I'm halfway through my first character creation and decided to try out the F Brush tool. I've seen quite a lot of folks using the tool. I do not have this tool. 
I've looked for the addon...with no results.

Where can I find a download for it? I would really appreciate it as I am still learning. I don't want to settle with sculptdraw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Brush* preset and a few others were [removed in 2.73](https://developer.blender.org/rB4b742caddce4eb9bae9afa3305e25f702c6ed840) because they were essentially [the same as other presets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3643/599):

> Some brushes really do the same thing and we have agreed not to offer
>   extra presets for one brush type. Removed those brushes from default
>   .blend. They are Polish (Flatten Contrast does the same), Brush (Does
>   the same as draw) and Draw from texpaint (where texdraw/draw does the
>   same)

---

Also note that the "F" is [not part of the brush's name](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3699/599), but rather indicates that it has a [*Fake User*](http://blender.org/manual/data_system/datablocks.html#fake-user).

Comment: I realise that it is supposed to be there by default although it's not. This would be the 3rd time I have installed blender but I do not have the brush. I also know that F is not part of the name but as my cousin calls it "F Brush" or "F Crease" maybe someone else may also call it that. Looking at what this picture has I also do not have polish either.

Comment: @CoreyMatthews Ah, my mistake. Looks like they were removed in 2.73, at least they were there in 2.72. Anyway, there was a lot of redundancy between brushes and it's likely this was cleaned up at some point. I don't have time at the moment, but later I'll look around and see if I can find the exact reason they were removed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this question cause I was really stumped. I figured that might be it. From what I've read up was that some couldn't really see a difference between the brushes. Anywho...there are always other ways around things. I just had to play around til I got the results I needed. Again thank you for taking the time.